# Woocommerce - Shipping methods not shown and shipping costs not calculated

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a webshop using Wordpress with:
- Avada theme
- plugin: Woocommerce
- plugin: Flexible shipping
- plugin: Polylang
- plugin: Hyyan WooCommerce Polylang Integration
- plugin: WP Ultimate Recipe

I created three shipping zones:
NL - local pickup and flexible shipping
EUR1 - flexible shipping
EUR2 - flexible shipping

Flexible shipping is based on weight of the product, a different shipping rate for different weights.

The problem is that the shipping methods are not shown on the website and that the customers can not select a method. Also no shipping rate is calculated before checkout.

All the shipping methods are checked 'enabled'. I have tried deactivating the plugin for flexible shipping, but also then no shipping rates are calculated. I've also been playing with the shipping options. The shipping options are currently defined as follows (sorry, in dutch) [shipping options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzdz6.png)

Avada should be compatible with Woocommerce, but could the theme be the problem anyway?
I've read that more people have issues with this, but I'v checked the solutions mentioned and can't get it to work. Can anybody give a suggestion on how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Do your products have shipping classes - [Doc link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-shipping-classes/#section-3) ?

Comment: No, I did not use shipping classes.

Comment: I don't think I need them because the shipping rates do not differ between products, just between amounts per product.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. In products in Woocommerce you can put a checkmark for the kind of product your selling. The checkmark was set at a kind of product that does not require shipping.